# CSS issue to align the box horizontally

Tags: css, asp-classic, crm, sage-crm

I am having some CSS issues in the asp page of Sage CRM. Some alignments are mismatching.

I am creating 4 blocks and four tables  with four different function.Each block will show the total balance. Now these four blocks are in vertical positions as

block 1
table 1;
block2
table2; and so on...

Each block is a div. Now I want all the blocks in horizontal position to be in one line like:

block 1   block 2   block3   block4

The issues is these properties (alignment of the boxes) are changing for the different persons in sage. For one person this code will match and all four boxes are in same line, for second person some boxes are below, for third person I can't find one of the box.

My div style css for four function is like below:

How to link the divs which are in four different functions in asp of sage

```
function fn_main()
    {
    + '<DIV div CLASS="bx" style="width: 15%;height: 67; overflow-n: scroll; scrollbar-arrow-color: blue; scrollbar-face-color: #e7e7e7; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #a0a0a0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#
    888888">'
    }

    function fn_1()
    {
    + '<DIV div CLASS="bx" style="width: 20%; height: 67;margin:-225px 0 0 225px;position: absolute;overflow: hidden;scrollbar-arrow-color: blue; scrollbar-face-color: #e7e7e7; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #a0a0a0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#888888">'            
    }

    function fn_2()
    {
    + '<DIV div CLASS="bx" style="width: 22%; height: 67;margin:-380px 0 0 470px;position: absolute;overflow: hidden; scrollbar-arrow-color: blue; scrollbar-face-color: #e7e7e7; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #a0a0a0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#888888">' 
    }

    function fn_3()
    {
     + '<DIV div CLASS="bx" style="width: 25%; height: 67;margin:-425px 0 0 625px;position: absolute;overflow: hidden;scrollbar-arrow-color: blue; scrollbar-face-color: #e7e7e7; scrollbar-3dlight-color: #a0a0a0; scrollbar-darkshadow-color:#888888">'   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.bx{clear: none; float: left;}
```

This will align all the divs to the left, making them appear in the same line!

And put px/em in the height :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding

```
display:inline-block
```

to each of the divs?

Comment: I tried but it is not working,I cant find my last div box in some pages

Comment: I meant try removing position:absolute and then add display:inline-block. If it doesn't work, we'll try something else.